# Create a Cumulative Sum Column in MySQL Based On an ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a "simplified" table that looks like this:

```
player  round  point
1       1      25   
2       1      18
3       1      15
1       2      18
2       2      25
3       2      15
```

I wanna create a view that calculates pointTot cumulatively based upon plrID

```
plrID  rndID  pnt  [pointTot]
1       1      25     25
2       1      18     18
3       1      15     15
1       2      18     43
2       2      25     43
3       2      15     30
```

I've been playing around with different methods for the last few hours.

I would need a variable var based upon the plrID

This is as far as I got without being able to work out how to create a
@psum[@plrID]

```
set @psum := 0;
select `plrID`, `rndID`, `pnt`, (@psum := @psum + `pnt`) as `pointTot`
from `table`
order by `plrID`;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using below query

```
select t.plrID,t.rndID,t.pnt,sum(t1.pnt) 
from table t 
join table t1 
on t.plrID = t1.plrID 
and t1.rndID<=t.rndID
group by plrID,rndID
```

Comment: Nice solution @Andrews.  You'll want to add in a `group by` clause: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b10f7/2

Comment: This just gives me a single ROW with a sum of something exponentially larger than the sum of everything together.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as:

```
select `plrID`, `rndID`, `pnt`,
       (@psum := if(@p = plrId, @psum + pnt,
                    if(@p := plrId, pnt, pnt)
                   )
       ) as pointTot
from `table` cross join
     (select @psum := 0, @p := -1) param
order by `plrID`, rndID;
```

You cannot add this as a view, because variables are not allowed in a view.  You can use this version:

```
select `plrID`, `rndID`, `pnt`,
       (select sum(t2.pnt)
        from `table` t2
        where t2.plrId = t.plrId and t2.rndId <= t.rndId
       ) as pointTot
from `table` t ;
```

Comment: Gordon fantastic! one other question, I can't add that as a view to my code. Would I have to execute this from a stored proc?

Comment: To build off of Gordon's solution, the summation using a variable depends upon each player being processed one at a time. To restore the original ordering using this method, you could wrap this up as a subquery http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b10f7/1

Comment: Annoyingly this isn't far off what I had about 2 hours ago. Thank you very much :D